# How to delete a project in SonarQube 5.3 if the search doesn't find it?

Tags: sonarqube

A few projects' analysis is failing with the following error:

org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
      o The project "com.xxx.myproject:myproject-api-test" is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project "com.xxx.myproject:myproject". If you really want to stop directly analysing project "com.xxx.myproject:myproject-api-test", please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project "com.xxx.myproject:myproject".

However, I am unable to find the project on the SonarQube frontend, therefore can't delete it.
I have tried browsing directly to what I imagined the URL for that project to be. That worked for one, but I have more projects with this problem and for those a URL is not available.
One more thing: I use multi-module projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get into the DB and do it from there. I did have a script on a previous job to fix this issue :(. I think I can explain what happened there without seeing anything in the DB.

1. You had a multi-module maven project which was running nice and easily.
2. Someone run a sonar build on one of the submodules. This updated the submodule in Sonar to become a top level module.
3. Someone deleted the submodule from sonar (UI) which actually doesn't delete it, but marks it as deleted. And this is also the reason why you cannot find it from the sonar UI.

What I remember doing was to

1. log on the database
2. find the row describing the top level module
3. find the row describing the submodule that is giving you trouble
4. update the row of the submodule to become a submodule (I remember there was a 'type' column or similar) and update the parent id from the step on 2. You might also un mark this as deleted.

I'm sorry that I cannot be of more help with the specific SQL queries.

Comment: This worked in most cases, except a couple for which I am unable to locate the module on the database!? Any idea on the cause and resolution for that case? I should mention that I am testing the upgrade SonarQube 4.0 > 4.5.6 > 5.3.

Comment: That's really odd. Are you saying that if you query the project/module table and search by the module id (e.g. 'com.xxx.myproject:myproject-api-test') you don't get any results? If this is the case, I'm not sure I can help, as I haven't seen this before. Something that 'might' work, is to run a sonar build with debug enabled and check if it logs out any queries it runs against the DB that might hint what is going on.

Comment: My bad. I was querying "name" rather than "kee" (in the projects table). For most projects, those coincidentally matched, but for a few others didn't. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Just a comment... the people on the sonar mailing list are also quite helpful in case you have other issues. I haven't checked it in a while, but it's another good place in case you don't get an answer here :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sonarqube version 5.1.x and ran into same problem. Executed mvn sonar:sonar on maven sub-module. To fix it, I updated the kee column products table for that project and set the value to :. After that logged in as admin into UI and did a bulk delete. Re-ran mvn sonar:sonar and able to verify the fix.